# Is it possible to connect to signals in a Gtk/GObject app without a reference to the sender widget?

Tags: python, gtk

I'm building a Gtk app in Python (Lutris, available on Github) where I emit a custom signal in a part of the app and I would like to connect to that signal in a totally different part of the app where the receiver doesn't have a reference to the widget that emitted the signal.

I was looking for a way to have a signal where any widget of the application could connect to it even without a reference to the widget. Is this possible to do with GObject? Or do I need to use something else, maybe DBus?

Comment: Doesn't Python send the sending widget as the first argument of the callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching a bit more on the issue I found a solution that would work.

On the receiving widget, instead of `connect`, `GObject.add_emission_hook` can be used to have something like:

```
GObject.add_emission_hook(SenderType, 'signal-name', on_signal_callback)
```

Unlike conventional callbacks, this one must return True otherwise it will only work once.